# php session sharing, in a desperate attempt to execute code in a different scope

Tags: php, session, ipc, cron-task

I wonder why something like this wouldn't work (actually doesn't work):

`4.php :`

```
<php
session_start();

$my_id = session_id();

$_SESSION['username'] = (($_SESSION['username'] == 'nimic') ? 's-a schimbat' : $_GET['test']);

file_put_contents('comm.g', PHP_EOL.$my_id, FILE_APPEND);

sleep(3); // can be left out

echo $_SESSION['username'];

?>
```

4.php is a simple page that only sets the "username" component of $_SESSION, then writes the session id to a file, after which it echoes the $_SESSION['username'] value.

Then:

`3.php :`

```
<php

while(true)
{
    if(file_exists("comm.g"))
    {
        $c = file("comm.g");
        unlink("comm.g");

        session_start();
        foreach($c as $k => $v)
        {
            if($v != '')
            {
                $my_id = session_id();
                session_write_close();
                session_id($v);
                session_start();
                file_put_contents("result.cc", $_SESSION['username'].'---'.$v.'END'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                $_SESSION['username'] = 'somethingelse';
                session_id($my_id);
                session_start();
            }
        }
        session_write_close();
    }
}
?>
```

3.php is run by a cronjob, every minute, for about 30 seconds (until server kills it). Anyway in `result.cc` I find (in those 30 available seconds) the expected result... the value of $_GET['test'].

But it does not modify the value of $_SESSION['username'], I didn't even expect such a behavior actually, I knew that sleep wouldn't be enough, but still, on a refresh shouldn't it be modified?...

I know that my code is awful, it is just a test, if it works it would be improved.

But I don't seem to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?
Actually I am doing a lot of things wrong, the system itself should not be used like this, I know that too, but still, right now this is my only option. I have more complicated ideas about this thing, but if this won't work, the others won't work either.

My intention actually is to execute code in separate thread so that I can escape some changes (like registering a wrapper for the file scheme, and having no power to unregister (restore) it when I need to, inside the wrapper class that is) that I made there. Unorthodox method, I know...

So, can you help with any ideas? Thank you.

#### EDIT 1

Even if lead me to an interesting idea @Ben's answer wasn't exact... Actually in cookies is kept only the session id, I replaced the need for cookies by using a file, so that the cronjob knew what session should be modified, I got the correct value for $_SESSION['username'] for any "registred" sessions, but even so, I was unable to modify the damn values, it was like they were marked readonly. Now, reconsidering, I found the idea still on it's feet, being viable, and a solution whatsoever.
So my questions still is up... WHY wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem: `3.php is run by a cronjob`.

The session requires cookies, which requires a web browser and browser state. If you run the script as a cron job, there is no session.

A solution to your actual problem that you might want to consider is Runkit Sandbox: http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php

Comment: Runkit Sandbox might be a solution indeed, but not an option for unfortunately. So I cannot install any extensions. And between those that are available, this is not among them.

Comment: @blind, Ah, I see it now. Your `session_start()` above the `foreach()` was throwing me off -- that line shouldn't do anything in the context of a cron, so I didn't even really look into the rest of your code. Also, there's no need to save the session id and restore it within that loop. Crons have no native session to store! That said, there are a number of subtle reasons why this might fail I'd suggest removing all the unnecessary code and then adding a "session_commit()" after altering a value. Don't know if that will fix it, but it's a possibility. I'll add another answer with a code example

Comment: And yes, session_commit is the same as session_write_close, but I mean to put it immediately after the data, not before you change the session back. You'll see what I mean in the code example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's an example of `3.php` with unnecessary code removed, and "session_write_close()" added immediately after the data assignment. Don't know if it will work, but it's worth a shot. Also, a while(true) loop with nothing to slow it down when the file doesn't exist will sit there and use 100% of a cpu (until the server kills it), not to mention constant file system accesses. Really, you should be adding a sleep in there to curb it. So without further ado:

```
<?php

while(true)
{
    if(file_exists("comm.g"))
    {
        $c = file("comm.g");
        unlink("comm.g");

        foreach($c as $k => $v)
        {
            if($v != '')
            {
                session_id($v);
                session_start();
                file_put_contents("result.cc", $_SESSION['username'].'---'.$v.'END'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                $_SESSION['username'] = 'somethingelse';
                session_write_close();
            }
        }
    }
    usleep(200000); // Sleep for 1/5 of a second, to avoid a 100% cpu hog and constant stream of file system accesses
}

?>
```

Comment: Now in a odd way it doesn't get me the value of $_SESSION['username'] in result.cc...  The error log says something like: [date time] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent in /***/3.php on line 15    OR     [date time] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in /***/3.php on line 15

Comment: @blind,m Oh, I just realized you are using `<php`, not `<?php`. I fixed that in my example, but you should fix that in your code too. Also, please make sure there are no blank lines (or any other output) before the opening `<?php`.

Comment: I had already checked that, before I left the comment I think, otherwise I would have returned to edit it... anyway, I tested it now, adding a minor modification to 4.php, an "echo" to see the $_SESSION['username'] before it will be modified into $_GET['test']... but still the output in result.cc is: `---9eb425a474c8c13d925edee9c1da2011`
`END` unfortunately, it's like the user session is already closed... as the session id from comm.g is useless